# WFS geotools Hashmap can not be parsed to SimpleFeature

Tags: wfs, java, geotools

I'm trying to implement a WFS client in Java using the Geotools. But everytime I tried to read the actual features I get following Error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature
```

It seems it is nested somewhere in

> (PullParserFeatureReader.java:84)
>   Requests to other WFS services work. So it seems to be something specific to this service, which I can't figure out.

My code looks like this

```
    Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", "https://geodaten.metropoleruhr.de/poi/poi?" );
    connectionParameters.put("WSFDataStoreFactory:WFS_STRATEGY", "mapserver");
    connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:MAXFEATURES", "1");

    WFSDataStoreFactory dsf = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
    WFSDataStore data = dsf.createDataStore( connectionParameters );

    String typeNames[] = data.getTypeNames();
    String typeName = typeNames[0];

    try {
        SimpleFeatureSource source = data.getFeatureSource(typeName);
        SimpleFeatureCollection fc = source.getFeatures();

        while(fc.features().hasNext()){
            SimpleFeature sf = fc.features().next();
            System.out.println(sf.getAttribute("name"));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, you are reliant on the version negotiation and are accepting the default output format. It may be better to force those to say 1.1.0 and "text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2" to limit the variables.

If that doesn't fix the issue then 
from the [GeoTools FAQ](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/xml/faq.html):

> Q: For WFS why does Parser return a Map?
>   This shows up as the following error:
>
> ClassCastException “java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   FeatureCollection”. To understand this error please remember that the
>   GML returned by a WFS GetFeatures request is a normal XML file, with a
>   reference to an XML schema at the top.
>
> For a WFS GetFeature response the schema reference is usually a
>   DescribeFeatureType call that returns an XML Schema.
>
> If this schema is incorrectly configured (common with MapServer) or
>   cannot be reached (common with restricted environments) our Parser
>   will give up guessing what is a Feature and just return the values in
>   a HashMap.
>
> Note If you are using the GML utility class it will perform a bit of
>   analysis and create an ad-hoc FeatureType in order to return you
>   Features. looking at the HashMaps returned building a feature type
>   that matches that kind of contents building features that match that
>   FeatureType This is similar to the approach taken by OGR; OGR figures
>   out where the “geometry” is; and then goes up two levels and assumes
>   those things are features. Both of these approaches are strictly a
>   work around for a common problem of misconfigured WFS servers. Here is
>   how to review the configuration of your WFS Server:
>
> If you are having a problem with a HashMap being returned when you
>   expect a Feature, you should check GetCapabilities responses for
>   remote server e.g. with browser:
>
> http://{URL}?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities After
>   that, ensure that  elements contain urls that actually
>   work
>
> In particular check that DescribeFeatureType responds with the
>   expected XML Schema

Now the server returns a valid [getcapabilities doc](https://geodaten.metropoleruhr.de/poi/poi?service=WFS&request=getcapabilities) which is good and it suggests we can try describeFeatureTypes - that seem to provide [valid schema](https://geodaten.metropoleruhr.de/poi/poi?service=wfs&request=describeFeatureType&featureType=ms:poi_alle_pois&version=1.1.0). But I'm not sure which feature type you are actually trying to download. Everything seemed to work for `ms:poi_polizei` which I picked at random.

**Update**

Using the following code I get no issues for any of the features in that server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.DefaultTransaction;
import org.geotools.data.Query;
import org.geotools.data.Transaction;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureStore;
import org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStoreFactory;
import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory2;
import org.opengis.filter.identity.FeatureId;
import org.opengis.filter.sort.SortBy;
import org.opengis.filter.sort.SortOrder;

public class FetchWFS {


  FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
  private URL baseURL;
  private DataStore datastore;
  private boolean auth = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FetchWFS test = new FetchWFS("http://geodaten.metropoleruhr.de/poi/poi");

    String[] names = test.getNames();
    for (String name : names) {
      System.out.print(name);
      SimpleFeatureCollection f = test.getData(name);
      System.out.println(" "+f.size()+" features");
      System.out.println("\t"+DataUtilities.first(f));
      System.out.println();
    }

  }

  public FetchWFS(String url) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    this(url, "", "");
  }

  public FetchWFS(String url, String user, String passwd) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    if (!user.isEmpty()) {
      auth = true;
    }
    baseURL = new URL(url);
    List<NameValuePair> nvp = URLEncodedUtils.parse(baseURL.toURI(), "UTF-8");
    NameValuePair service = new BasicNameValuePair("service", "wfs");
    NameValuePair request = new BasicNameValuePair("request", "getCapabilities");
    NameValuePair version = new BasicNameValuePair("version", "1.1.0");
    HashMap<String, NameValuePair> parts = new HashMap<>();
    parts.put(service.getName(), service);
    parts.put(request.getName(), request);
    parts.put(version.getName(), version);
    for (NameValuePair part : nvp) {

      if (part.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("SERVICE")) {
        // We don't care what they think this should be
      } else if (part.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("REQUEST")) {
        // This must be getCapabuilities so we ignore them
      } else if (part.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("VERSION")) {
        System.out.println("Changing version to " + part.getValue());
        parts.put(version.getName(), part);
      } else {
        parts.put(part.getName(), part);
      }
    }

    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme(baseURL.getProtocol());
    builder.setHost(baseURL.getHost());
    builder.setPort(baseURL.getPort());
    builder.setPath(baseURL.getPath());
    List<NameValuePair> p = new ArrayList<>();
    p.addAll(parts.values());
    builder.setParameters(p);
    // builder.addParameter("viewparams", "q:\"mySolrQuery\"");
    URI uri = builder.build();
    System.out.println(uri);
    baseURL = uri.toURL();
    // fetch the DataStore
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, baseURL);
    if (auth) {
      params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.USERNAME.key, user);
      params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.PASSWORD.key, passwd);
    }
    params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.WFS_STRATEGY.key, "mapserver");
    datastore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
  }

  public SimpleFeatureType getSchema(String name) throws IOException {
    return datastore.getSchema(name);
  }

  public String[] getNames() throws IOException {
    return datastore.getTypeNames();
  }

  public SimpleFeatureCollection getData(String name) throws IOException {
    SimpleFeatureSource source = datastore.getFeatureSource(name);
    return source.getFeatures();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked for me! Thoudh I'd like to use v2.0.0 of the WFS. Changing the version results in another issue.

Comment: I just spotted the v2.0 issue - I'll look into it at the weekend. You can filter the returned feature collection using a Query -  SimpleFeatureSource source = datastore.getFeatureSource(name);

    Query query = new Query();
    /*query.setSortBy(new SortBy[] { ff.sort("name", SortOrder.ASCENDING) });
    query.setStartIndex(start);
    query.setMaxFeatures(size);*/
    query.setFilter(ECQL.toFilter("name='Erlebnisbad Maximare'"));
    return source.getFeatures(query);

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll be on holiday next week. So no rush. 
Figured out with the filter already. Thanks once again!